OXALIS AS4 Access Point for PEPPOL
I'm trying to complete the installation of the OXALIS AS4 on my Linux server with Tomcat.
I followed the documentation found on https://github.com/OxalisCommunity/Oxalis-AS4/blob/master/docs/installation/index.md .
First I installed the AS2, then I installed the AS4.
Both modules seem to start :
https://peppol2.netfly.be/oxalis/as2
https://peppol2.netfly.be/oxalis/as4
But it's unclear for me how to fine-tune the configuration (oxalis.conf).
Does anyone have experience of such an installation ?
How to configure the "trustedstore" ?
How to configure the database ?
Etc...
I tried to find precise documentation of OXALIS, with an example of a complete configuration of AS4, but found only partial information.
Many thanks for help
